# Trying to record multiple button selections (using an array?)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

I'm trying to record which buttons are selected in a menu. Context: I use a map function because the number and colors of buttons are determined by the elements in myList and myColors. However, in other cases, myList and myColors will have different elements in them.

Users can click on as many buttons as they'd like and when they click done, they move onto a new trial. At the moment, I don't have a way to record which buttons are selected (when there is more than one selected).

Currently, you can see two commented out sections where I was attempted to do this but neither works. I think a good solution would be to list the selected buttons in an array when the user clicks "done". An output like this would be ideal (e.g., list = [A, B, D] or whatever buttons the user had selected), but I haven't been able to do this yet. Any help would be appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }

    #buttonGallery {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      width: 155px;
    }

    #done {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <div id="buttonGallery">
      <!-- add this line -->
      <div id="done">
        <p>done</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let $buttonGallery = $("#buttonGallery");
      let myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
      let myColors = ["red", "green", "blue", "red"];

      $buttonGallery.children(":not(#done)").remove();

      myList.map(function(letter, index) {
        let $button = $("<div></div>")
          .addClass("buttons")
          .attr("id", "button_" + letter)
          .html("<p>" + letter + "</p>")
          .on("mouseenter", function() {
            $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
          })
          .on("mouseleave", function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
              $(this).css("background", "transparent");
            }
          })
          .on("click", function() {
            $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            // var id = $('.buttons.selected:eq(0)').attr('id');
            // var short_id = id.split("_")[1];
            // var list = [];
            // list.push(short_id);
            // console.log(list);

          })
        $("#done").before($button);
      });


      $("#done").on("click", clearColor);

      function clearColor() {
        // var id = $('.buttons.selected:eq(0)').attr('id');
        // var short_id = id.split("_")[1];
        // var list = [];
        // list.push(short_id);
        // console.log(list);

        $(".buttons").css({
          backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        });
        $(".buttons").removeClass('selected');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using JavaScript**

***NOTE:*** *I did not use your code in my example, just how this could be done using a loop on your button elements, recording the click events within the loop and pushing those values into an array.*

You could query the selectors of the buttons, I use `class` and `querySelectorAll` in my example. Then create an array to hold the values of the clicked buttons. Run a for loop on the length of your buttons element list. Use an event listener on each iteration and if it is triggered with a click, record that in your array using push.

I chose to use an array with the values of the color for each button in my example and when I created the display of the buttons, I placed the color value into the text content and used that to get the value of the color chosen when the user clicks the button.

Use includes to see if the user already selected that color, so the `array.push()` only records it once.

Optional, empty the `clicked` array once you do something with the clicked array by setting the array to `= []`.

```js
let buttonsArr = [
  'red',
  'green',
  'blue',
  'yellow',
  'orange'
];
let display = document.getElementById('display');
let done = document.getElementById('done');
for (let i in buttonsArr) {
  display.innerHTML += "<button class='buttons' id='" + buttonsArr[i] + "'>" + buttonsArr[i] + "</button>";
}
let clicked;
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons');
for (let n = 0; n < buttons.length; n++) {
  clicked = [];
  buttons[n].addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!clicked.includes(buttons[n].textContent)) {
      clicked.push(buttons[n].textContent);
    }
    console.log(clicked); //--> `clicked` now holds the values of each color the user clicked on

  })

}
done.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('colors').textContent = clicked;

  //optional empty the array once you do something with it. 
  clicked = [];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display"></div><p id="colors"></p>
<input type="button" value="Done" id="done">
```